# Changing Color of Circle with Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, colors

I'm just trying to change the color of my drawn circle with a timer. I have implemented following code into my "`onCreate`" method:

```
     Timer t = new Timer();
     t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() { 
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     Drawing.switchColor();
                 }
             });
         }
     },
     1000,
     1000);
```

The method `switchColor()` does the following action:

```
    public static void switchColor() {
    Random r = new Random(30);
    int random = r.nextInt();
    if(random < 10) {
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(random >10 && random < 20) {
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else {
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

When I run this, the color stays at it's default.

Does anyone know whether I have to use a handler within or a different timer model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You changed the title of the question to "Solved", please change it back and instead clic on the tick next to the answer that solved your question. (If it's your own answer it doesn't matter)

Comment: Thank you! All you have to do is accept your answer and you're done C: (I guess you have to wait 1 or 2 hours or so I don't remember)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a suitable solution:

```
//-------------------Part 1 of AddCircleTimer------------------------
     //Declare the timerAddCircle
     timerAddCircle = new Timer();
     timerAddCircle.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             TimerMethodAddCircle();
         }
     }, 1000, 1000);

 //-------------------Part 2 of AddCircleTimer------------------------
private void TimerMethodAddCircle()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer and runs in the same thread as the timer.
    //We call the method that will work with the UI through the runOnUiThread method.
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Add);
}

private Runnable Timer_Add = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               
    //Do something to the UI thread here
         Drawing.addCircle();
         d.invalidate();
    }
};
//-------------------END Part 2 of AddCircleTimer------------------------
```

This works very fine and I can use it for even more timers and different methods!

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Your `t.start()` is missing, either in onCreate, onStart, or onResume, depending on when you want to start your timer.

Comment: if I put in "t.start();" directy after "t.scheduleAtFixedRate(....1000,1000);" an error occurs saying --> The method start() is undefined for the type Timer <-- Do I have to add a TimerTask?